# android studio, debug.keystore missing

Tags: android

After building my project on Android Studio 1.2 on Ubuntu 14.04 I can't get any debug.keystore on the ./android folder which I need for the google maps API. I tried it again and again but could not get it. Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 7):

According to documentation..
debug keystore resides in path : $HOME/.android/debug.keystore
and if it is not there, it will generate it automatically (After you test your application in debug mode)

read this from [android developer documentation](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html).

Alternatively, you can generate a keystore without Eclipse with the following JDK command from wither a Windows command prompt or Cygwin with this command:

```
keytool -genkeypair -alias androiddebugkey -keypass android -keystore debug.keystore -storepass android -dname "CN=Android Debug,O=Android,C=US" -validity 9999
```

Keytool is a part of the JDK and needs to be in the system PATH to be used in this way. The path should be something like: C:\\bin

Once generated, be sure to copy the keystore file into the proper location. If you ran the command from your Cygwin home directory (the directory cygwin starts in), you will find the debug.keystore file here: C:\\home\\

Answer (score 0):

A more practical answer can be found at [Missing debug.keystore](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63064024/13090794)

Even though the answer on the following link was answered from a windows perspective I still believe it will help you solve your problem.