# Android Studio issue missing missing debug.keystore

Tags: java, android, android-keystore

Every time I want to sign my aok I get the failure `Missing debug.keystore` it says that it actually should me located under this path Store: `C:\Users\jamie\.android\debug.keystore` but there isn't any keystore file.

How can I create one ?

Please explain it for a really silly person.

#### Android Studio Messages Gradle Build

[image]

#### File Manager

[image]

Answer (score 21):

I know this comes late, but I hope it helps those that come in the future. To generate a new keystore, do the following:

1. Type `keytool -alias "AndroidDebugKey" -genkeypair` in the terminal of your Android studio and give it a password of **`android`**.
2. The rest of the fields or questions asked after that don't matter, so just press **Enter**.
3. Go to your home directory (*C:\Users\*) and look for a file named as `.keystore`.
4. Rename `.keystore` to `debug.keystore`.
5. Now copy and paste it to (*C:\Users<YOUR USERNAME>\.android*).
6. Re-run the signReport task to generate a new key for APP.

Comment: thanks dude. this saved me so much time

Comment: Am glad you liked it

Comment: what about linux?

Comment: this is the only thing that worked for me! thanks so much

Answer (score 2):

You can generate a keystore using the keytool. It should be included in your JDK -

```
-genkeypair {-alias alias} {-keyalg keyalg} {-keysize keysize} 
{-sigalg sigalg} [-dname dname] [-keypass keypass] {-validity valDays} 
{-storetype storetype} {-keystore keystore} [-storepass storepass] {-providerClass provider_class_name {-providerArg provider_arg}} 
{-v} {-protected} {-Jjavaoption}
```

[Key Tool Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/keytool.html)

You can set the location of your keystore in the gradle file. For example -

```
...
android {
    ...
    defaultConfig { ... }
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file("myreleasekey.keystore")
            storePassword "password"
            keyAlias "MyReleaseKey"
            keyPassword "password"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            ...
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
}
...
```

[Signing Applications](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html)