# Missing keystore in Flutter

Tags: flutter, keystore, keytool

I want to get the SHA-1 code, but I encountered an error.

> C:\Users\erdem\AndroidStudioProjects\flutter_app\android>gradlew
> signinReport

[Missing Keystore](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rr7HO.png)

how can I solve this problem?

Comment: add more explanation...how ask -> https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: make sure you follow these steps refer `https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android`,`https://medium.com/@psyanite/how-to-sign-and-release-your-flutter-app-ed5e9531c2ac` @EDMGL

Comment: I'm facing the same issue. Did you find a fix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was trying to get the SHA1 but I couldn't get because of the missing keystore error, I tried that and it worked for me I don't know if it really works.

If you have your own jks file and did lead it with key.properties but still gives the error Missing Keystore that worked for me :

1. Type `keytool -alias "AndroidDebugKey" -genkeypair` in the terminal of your android studio give it a password of android.
2. The rest of the fields or questions asked after that don't matter so just press Enter.
3. Go to your home directory (C:\Users) and look for a file named as `.keystore`.
4. Rename `.keystore` to `debug.keystore.`
5. Now copy and paste it to (C:\Users.android).
6. Re-run the signReport task to generate a new key for APP.

source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63064024/7767761

Answer (score 4):

Had the same issue. Cleanest fix I found is to generate a debug key:

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -storepass android -alias androiddebugkey -keypass android -dname "CN=Android Debug,O=Android,C=US"
```

`gradlew signinReport` will work after that.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10981870)

Comment: This worked for me. I was getting "Missing Keystore" for the release config. But when I execute `gradlew signinReport `, I was able to find out the SHA1 key.

Comment: keytool error: java.lang.Exception: The -keyalg option must be specified.
Add param `-keyalg RSA` to fix this. 
`keytool -genkey -v -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -storepass android -alias androiddebugkey -keypass android -keyalg RSA -dname "CN=Android` Debug,O=Android,C=US"

Answer (score 2):

You can follow [these steps](https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android):

Create a file named /android/key.properties that contains a reference to your keystore:

```
storePassword=<password from previous step>
keyPassword=<password from previous step>
keyAlias=key
storeFile=<location of the key store file, such as /Users/<user name>/key.jks>
```

Answer (score 0):

**I had the same problem.**
This error comes when **dubug.keystore** file is missing in **users/"Name"/.android/** directory and can be resolved by simply run your app on any **mobile device** it will create the **debug.keystore** file in the directory now the error should be gone on running **signingreport**.

cheers..!